# am trying that when I click on spinner item, list view shows further details of that item

Tags: android

When I click a spinner item,I would like list view to shows more details on that item. 

i.e if I select Student from Spinner then list view should show student names.

```
spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(SpinnerActivity.this, parent.getItemAtPosition(position)+" ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

What is the right way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Create an `ArrayList` with Strings(Student names). Now create an `ArrayAdapter` in onCreate() which contains the Students `ArrayList`.
In the EventListener(onItemSelected) of the `Spinner`, check for the Spinner-item text. If it's "Students" set the `ArrayAdapter` of the `Spinner` to the Students-ArrayAdapter which you initialized in onCreate();

**onCreate():**

```
arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
arrayList.add("Bob");
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList);
```

**onItemSelected EventListener:**

```
if(view.getText().toString().equals("Students"){
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```